# How to run a script when switching from run level 3 to 0

Tags: linux, centos, runlevel

I need to run a script when the server is going for a shutdown i.e. run level 0. But the catch here is, I need to make a curl call in the script which is not possible in run level 0 as the network will be down.

So my question is how can I achieve this ?

Basically what I am looking for is a solution to run a script when the system goes from run level 3 to run level 0.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that combining all this together

- Check the current run-level with `$ runlevel`, `$ who -r`, etc.
- Make an executable script in `/etc/init.d/` where you check if the current run level is `3`.
  And perform your operations you want.
- Make a symlink in `/etc/rc0.d/` with target to your script.
- The name of the symlink has to satisfy to some criteria in order to run before the networking services are disabled, check them [here](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/OSAdminG/sstT.etcrc.html). Of course it depends on your host, and will be specific to your configuration.

That's it, this should work !